# Reading iPhones call, SMS and data usage

Tags: iphone, sms, phone-call

my team is currently in the feasibility phase of a 'usage meter app' iPhone app. We would like to read the phone's total count of

1. Sent SMS
2. Made calls
3. Data sent and received

We are not after the call history like other posts or like this blog post reading the actual call logs (http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/). All we need is the stats and how they change over the course of time.

Answer (score 4):

As of iOS 4.0, it's no longer possible to do that call history trick described in the blog entry you posted there.  Apple took away that "artefact of the implementation".

If you are a registered developer and have access to Apple's "private" dev forums (at https://devforums.apple.com), do a search on "call history" over the past year or two and you'll see Apple engineering attesting to that fact in the first few threads you'll find.

You'll probably want to file an enhancement request at http://bugreporter.apple.com, but I wouldn't expect a positive outcome immediately as this probably raises security and privacy issues.

As for network statistics, you can get per-interface stats via ["`getifaddrs`"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/system/conceptual/manpages_iphoneos/man3/getifaddrs.3.html) (man page linked for you).  You get the list of addresses on that system, and then for each AF_LINK address, cast the ifa_data field to a (const struct if_data *) and access the interface statistics from there.

(there are also two caveats -- these stats are all reset to zero at startup time, and there's no easy way to easily tell which interface is cellular versus WiFi).